# Embedding Multimedia Videos on full frame in beamer without any background

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I'm embedding multimedia videos in my `beamer` document using `multimedia` package with the following code.

```
\movie[height = 0.6\textwidth, width = 0.8\textwidth, poster, showcontrols] {}{Video.mp4}
```

It works fine except it adds black background on right-left or/and top-bottom for some videos. I wonder how to remove this background and also how to expand the videos for full frame in size. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Edited**

Minimum Working Example with attached video.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Umpire Decision Review System}

\begin{block}{Umpire Decision Review System}

\begin{center}
\movie[height = 0.6\textwidth, width = 0.8\textwidth, poster, showcontrols] {}{DRS2.mp4}
\end{center} 

\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edited 2**

Video has been uploaded.

[Link to Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw0kfaLvmf8HMUpON0J3Q2xTWTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Would you like to provide a MWE? (after cut down the video to 3 sec or so.) By the way, your title said **full frame** but the code said `height=.6\textwidth`. Is not it contradictable?

Comment: Please post video somewhere and provide the link if possible.

Comment: Could not figure out where to post the video @HarishKumar. Would appreciate if you tell me any website for this or can I attach you video in an email. Thanks

Comment: You can put it in dropbox or google drive.

Comment: Can't you just make sure to set the aspect ratio of the `\movie` to the same as the video file? I mean, the width:height ratio is  4:3 for the `\movie`, but the video file is clearly 16:9 or thereabouts (judging by the screenshot).

Comment: I agree with @TorbjørnT. You appear to have specified a size, whose ratios are different than the aspect ratio of the video.  Can you perhaps only specify the width and let it determine the height based on the video?

Comment: Can you provide the mp4 file?

Comment: Any news here on the video? Did you try using Google Drive to upload it?

Comment: Video has been uploaded @HarishKumar,  gonzalomedina.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Video has been uploaded. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code extends the video to full pagewidth, full pageheight or both, depending on the video aspect ratio (and that of the presentation PDF):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
         \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {%
           \includemedia[
             addresource=DRS2.mp4,
             activate=pageopen,transparent,
             flashvars={source=DRS2.mp4},
             width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight
           ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
         };
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or using the `multimedia` package. (Note that MP4 video format may not work in A-Reader with this media inclusion method. AVI+MS Video 1 codec seems to be the right format to be chosen here.):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
         \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {%
           \movie[height = \paperheight, width = \paperwidth, poster, showcontrols] {}{DRS2.mp4}%
         };
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexG for your answer.  I'm not getting video output. It is simply blank. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208  It should work in Adobe Reader on Windows and OSX, and in Foxit (also Windows). Could you try another video file such as `random.mp4` from the `media9` package? Perhaps your video has the wrong codec (h264 is required)?

Comment: The screenshot looks like Okular being the PDF viewer. So try the second code box.

Comment: Do all video controls (play, stop, etc) work in such an example? I am trying to reproduce your proposals here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304681/13173

Comment: @AlexG, I'm getting the same result as @MYaseen208 did - audio but no video.  FYI, this happens when using your `multimedia` package-related code.  My video plays fine if I substitute your "inside the frame" code with this single line: `\movie[width=10.4cm,height=7.8cm,autostart]{}{test_movie.avi}`.  Oddly enough, your code was working for a few tries, then quit working...

Comment: @AlexG, after some more fooling around, I've been able to determine that your said `multimedia` related code works.  The problem was that I was using the "latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf" compiling workaround in order to get autostart to work (known bug for my version of beamer (Debian Squeeze)).  In order to have success with your code, I first need to compile using "pdflatex", followed by said "latex..." scheme.